# How to run a native process in flex library?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, air, flash-builder

It could run a native process in an adobe air application by enable extendedDesktop.
But if create an flex library, does it support running an native process.
If yes, how to configure it?

Thanks.

Comment: I removed the Adobe tag and added Flash Builder; since it seems you are referring to creating Flex Library projects.

Answer (score 3):

NativeProcess APIs are only exposed via the Adobe AIR Runtime.  You cannot us them in a browser based Flash application.

However, you are more than welcome to use them in a Flex application that targets the Adobe AIR desktop Runtime.  The approach is no different than a non-Flex application built for AIR.

---

I missed the fact that your question specified using the libraries in a Flex Library Project.  You should have no issues using the libraries in the Flex Library project as long as you select the "Include Air Libraries" option when you create the library project in Flash Builder.

Comment: @Slomojo My bad I missed that clarification of the original question.  I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a Flex Library project in Flash Builder, you have an option to **Include Air Libraries**.

Your library project will then allow you to use Air API's such as NativeProcess.